# Find inverse of this function...

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$f(x) = \sin(x)-\cos(x)$
I got to this point: $$f^2(x)=1-\sin(2x)$$
But I have no idea what to do next. Please help me, give me a hint :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this function **is not invertible**, as it is not injective.

$$f(x)=f(x+2k\pi), \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Although it can be inverted on some small intervals such as $[a,b]$ where $a=\max \limits_x \{ f(x)=0, x<0 \}$ and $b=\min\limits_x \{ f(x)=1, x>0 \}$  simply find such interval by solving $$f(x)=0$$
and $$f(x)=1$$
and then try to invert the function there.

It should be helpful, that
$$f^2(x)=1-sin(2x) \iff 1-f^2(x)=sin(2x)$$

and on the limited domain of $\arcsin$ you have

$$2x=\arcsin(1-f^2(x)) \iff x = \frac{\arcsin(1-f^2(x))}{2}$$

but the most helpful idea is to look at its [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29-cos%28x%29), which looks like scaled and shifted sinusoid, it should give you a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: rewrite the initial function as $f(x)=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x)-\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x)\right)$ an then as $\sqrt{2}\,\sin(x-?)\;$ (or as $\;-\sqrt{2}\,\cos(x+?)\,$).

Answer (score 1):

From $$f(x) =y= \sin(x)-\cos(x)$$ follow that
$$f^2(x)=y^2=(\sin(x)-\cos(x))^2=\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x=1-\sin(2x)$$
since
$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$

$$\sin(2x)=1-f^2(x)=1-y^2$$

$$2x=\arcsin(1-y^2)$$

$$x=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(1-y^2)$$